# Double-escaping percent symbol (%) in Canvas.drawText

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know why I have to double-escape the percent symbol (%) when trying to string-format float values to draw on a canvas? See the relevant lines of code below...

```
float mValue = .25F;    
String percent = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.0f%%%%", mValue * 100);
canvas.drawText(percent, 0, percent.length() - 1, posX, posY, mTextPaint);
```

This will render `25%` on the view canvas. If I try the following string format...

```
String percent = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.0f%%", mValue * 100);
```

it will simply render `25` without the percent symbol. Is there anything obvious I'm missing here?
I'm running this on an emulator with API level 27, compiling with API Level 28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best bet would be that `.drawText()` cuts off the last char in your string. As when I just try to format the percent it actually has "%%" at the end.

Try using the code below without the string range to draw the full text and see if it does get cut off.

```
canvas.drawText(percent, posX, posY, mTextPaint);
```

Comment: Correct, as the other answer pointed out, the docs are not inline with the implementation

Answer (score 1):

Weirdly enough, the docs mentions the end parameter to be stringlength-1

> - @param end (end - 1) is the index of the last character in text to draw

But looking at the source code of the function that omits the start/end parameters in BaseCanvas, they use string.length() for the end parameter.

```
public void drawText(@NonNull String text, float x, float y, @NonNull Paint paint) {
...
    nDrawText(mNativeCanvasWrapper, text, 0, text.length(), x, y, paint.mBidiFlags,
                paint.getNativeInstance(), paint.mNativeTypeface);
}
```

So it looks like it's just trimming your last character my dude. Remove the "- 1", or just use the function that omits that start/end parameters like so:

```
canvas.drawText(percent, posX, posY, mTextPaint);
```